# Android Google Play Service: Best practices to make location request

Tags: android, gps, location, google-play-services, updates

Below is the current quote from the official guide [site](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest) for LocationRequest API

> In between these two extremes is a very common use-case, where
>   applications definitely want to receive updates at a specified
>   interval, and can receive them faster when available, but still want a
>   low power impact. These applications should consider
>   PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY combined with a faster
>   setFastestInterval(long) (such as 1 minute) and a slower
>   setInterval(long) (such as 60 minutes). They will only be assigned
>   power blame for the interval set by setInterval(long), but can still
>   receive locations triggered by other applications at a rate up to
>   setFastestInterval(long). This style of request is appropriate for
>   many location aware applications, including background usage. Do be
>   careful to also throttle setFastestInterval(long) if you perform
>   heavy-weight work after receiving an update - such as using the
>   network.

My concern relates to these methods

```
LocationRequest setFastestInterval(long millis)
```

Explicitly set the fastest interval for location updates, in milliseconds.

```
LocationRequest setInterval(long millis)
```

Set the desired interval for active location updates, in milliseconds.

Let's say numbers...
If I set interval=30s and fastest=8s, then at t=8, t=16, t=24 (multiples of 8) I get updates from other applications? What if there are no running location-aware apps? 
At 30s can I see a new update? Is that update counted as a power consumption of my app? How is it estimated?

So if this is correct, then what is a good relation between these two parameters to get real time updates without consuming a lot of power? For example interval=6 x fastest?

I would have tried myself but I cannot repeat the scenario described by the guide, I can't also distinguish which updates are power blamed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your app can continuously track location, it needs to get the location of the device at regular intervals. While you can get a device's location with [getLastLocation()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi), a more direct approach is to request periodic updates from the fused location provider. In response, the API updates your app periodically with the best available location, based on the currently-available location providers such as WiFi and GPS.

Before requesting location updates, your app must connect to location services and make a location request. Once a location request is in place you can start the regular updates by calling [`requestLocationUpdates()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi). Do this in the [onConnected()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks) callback provided by Google API Client, which is called when the client is ready.

Try to read the [`Location Strategies`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html), the strategies described in this guide apply to the platform location API in android.location. Also, show the for [`obtaining user location and defining a Model for the Best Performance'](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html)